# How to apply filter on array content in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which contain the data in an array format as shown below .

```
db.mycollection.save(
{
    "username": "jain",
    "options": [
        {
            "expiration_dt": "2016-01-15",
            "isMini": false
        },
        {
            "expiration_dt": "2014-01-18",
            "isMini": true
        },
        {
            "expiration_dt": "2014-01-18",
            "isMini": false
        }
    ]
}
)
```

written  a query in such a way that , it will sort the elements of an array named 'options' based on expiration_dt field and returns  the first one of the obtained result .

This is the query which does that work

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({$match : {"username" : "jain"}},{$unwind: "$options"},{$sort: {"options.expiration_dt":1}},{$limit : 1})
```

My question is that , can i include filter based on  **isMini** field  in the above query ( Because right now the problem i am facing is that if an array is consisting of same **expiration_dt** , it is returning me the first matching element present in that array .
So i want to include one more filter based on **isMini** attribute so that it returns me the correct data even if it has got same expiration_dt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query as follows so that it will only find the sub document that has **isMini=false**

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$options"},
  {$match : {"username" : "jain", "options.isMini" : false}},
  {$sort: {"options.expiration_dt":1}},
  {$limit : 1}
)
```